# Cancel Order in Magento 2 using REST api fails

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am working on a third party call to cancel an order on **Magento 2.2.1** using the `REST API`.  From swagger it seems that all I need to do is POST to `/V1/orders/{id}/cancel;` no payload necessary.  However this is failing in my app and when I try to test it in Swagger I get the below error.Is there something missing or a possible bug?

```
{
  "messages": {
    "error": [
      {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function allowStockUpdate() on string in /var/www/magento/app/code/WiseRobot/ChannelAdvisorAPI/Helper/Stock.php:458\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/magento/app/code/WiseRobot/ChannelAdvisorAPI/Helper/Stock.php(85): WiseRobot\\ChannelAdvisorAPI\\Helper\\Stock->_exportQty(155)\n#1 /var/www/magento/app/code/WiseRobot/ChannelAdvisorAPI/Observer/StockAfterSaveStockItemObserver.php(49): WiseRobot\\ChannelAdvisorAPI\\Helper\\Stock->exportQty(155)\n#2 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): WiseRobot\\ChannelAdvisorAPI\\Observer\\StockAfterSaveStockItemObserver->execute(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#3 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(WiseRobot\\ChannelAdvisorAPI\\Observer\\StockAfterSaveStockItemObserver), Object(Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer))\n#4 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-staging/Model/Event/Manager.php(97): Magento\\' in '/var/www/magento/app/code/WiseRobot/ChannelAdvisorAPI/Helper/Stock.php' on line 458",
        "trace": "Trace is not available."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below API for Cancel Order.

**API Name:** Cancel Order API

**Description:** Cancels a specified order.

**API URL:** {baseurl}/rest/V1/orders/{orderId}/cancel

**Authorization:** Use "Admin Token"

**Method:** POST

**Response:** true

Hope it help!